# "443 port seems to be closed" Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer

Tags: https, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application where I am trying to set up https / SSL

I have used the aws cli to import my certificates using IAM.

After creating a classic load balancer from [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html#configure-https-listener) and setting up all security groups and main netowork ACL inbound and outbound to Type: HTTP Port: 80 Source: 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 and HTTPS 443 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0

I am still getting the error "443 port seems to be closed, check your firewall/server configuration."

Comment: What do you get when you curl -I the https on the load balancer and also if you hit the backend directly on the traffic port?

Comment: When I curl -I to the https , I get failed to connect ... port 443: Timed out, but if I do
curl -I http, I get:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0  2077    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2077
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 18:57:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.10
Connection: keep-alive